# Time limit in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I need a help with time-limit. I want to show user how many time he has got to rent a car. 
This is my views:

```
class CarRentView(RedirectView):
    permanent = False
    query_string = True
    model = Car 

def date_of_return(request):
    car = Car.objects.all()
    car.rent = True
    date_of_rent = datetime.now()
    date_of_rent = car.save()
    car_return_date = date_of_rent+timedelta(days=30)
    return render(request, 'cars','car_return_date')
```

and when I want to do this in my template:

```
{{ car_return_date }}
```

there is nothing and I don't know, what's wrong. Is there any possibility to show return date and after this make a count?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the render function differently:

```
return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {'cars': car, 'car_return_date': car_return_date})
```

See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) for more information.

Besides, I don't think you are setting the `car.rent` correctly, since you are setting it on **all** cars.

Answer (score 0):

Variables that you return to your template need to be returned as part of a context dictionary. So you would have:

```
return render(request, 'my_template.html', {'car': car, 'car_return_date': car_return_date})
```

The `car_return_date` variable will then be available in your template using:

```
{{ car_return_date }}
```

You will also probably want to use the date filter when outputting the `datetime` object. For example, you could use:

```
{{ car_return_date|date:"j N Y" }}
```

Comment: It isn't error, {{ car_return_date|date:"j N Y }} on the teplate don't show any date

Comment: Does `{{ car_return_date }}` by itself return anything?

Comment: {{ car_return_date }} nothing return

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing `date_of_rent` to `last_date_of_rent` by adding 30 days to it. And then, saving `last_date_of_rent` to the models. So you can use, `last_date_of_rent` directly in the templates. Further the use of in-built template filter `timeuntil` will return the desired. -

`{{ car.last_date_of_rent|timeuntil }}`

Documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#timeuntil